# ast.literal_eval() support for set literals in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, set, literals, abstract-syntax-tree

In the [What’s New in Python 2.7](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features) document it says that support for set literals was back-ported from Python 3.1. However it appears that this support was not extended to the `ast` module's `literal_eval()` function, as illustrated below.

Was this intentional, an oversight, or something else — and what are the cleanest workarounds for creating a literal set from a string representation? (I assume the following works in Python 3.1+, right?)

```
import ast
a_set = {1,2,3,4,5}
print(a_set) 
print(ast.literal_eval('{1,2,3,4,5}'))
```

Output showing error message:

```
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\setliterals.py", line 4, in <module>
    print ast.literal_eval('{1,2,3,4,5}')
  File "...\Python\lib\ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "...\Python\lib\ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

P.S. The only workaround I can think of is to use `eval()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using this for converting columns in a pandas DataFrame (`df[col] = df[col].apply(to_set)`. Might be useful for anyone finding this question. It may not be as fast but it avoids using `eval`.

```
def to_set(set_str):
    """
    Required to get around the lack of support for sets in ast.literal_eval. 
    It works by converting the string to a list and then to a set.

    Parameters
    ----------
    set_str : str
        A string representation of a set.

    Returns
    -------
    set

    Raises
    ------
    ValueError
        "malformed string" if the string does not start with '{' and and end 
        with '}'.

    """
    set_str = set_str.strip()
    if not (set_str.startswith('{') and set_str.endswith('}')):
        raise ValueError("malformed string")

    olds, news = ['{', '}'] , ['[',']']
    for old, new in izip(olds, news):        
        set_str = set_str.replace(old, new)

    return set(literal_eval(set_str))
```

Comment: Clever workaround, but only if you know in advance that the string contains a set literal. I'd also suggest stripping leading and trailing whitespace so the `startswith` and `endswith` checks don't reject otherwise valid strings.

Answer (score 0):

From the bug report: http://bugs.python.org/issue10091

Raymond Hettinger says:

> ast.literal_eval's docs:
>
> 'The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python
>   literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans,
>   and None.'

I believe we can conclude from this document that the matter is not necessarily a bug, since the set literal was backported from Python 3.2 to 3.1 and 2.7. It *is* something that a Python 2.7 user of `ast.literal` should be aware of.

Comment: Other comments in the bug thread say "it's arguably a bug". From the entire discussion it sounds like not including it was an arbitrary decision made by the release manager when the lack of support was pointed out. From my own point of view, this means that set literals have only been _partially_ backported to 2.7 if they lack `ast.literal_eval()` support -- even if the fact is effectively documented by omission.

Comment: @martineau thanks, that's worth pointing out. I'm using bug in the sense of the things that are ok to fix that don't break current functionality, and based on Hettinger's response and my contextual understanding, he didn't consider it a bug, or if he did, he didn't consider it worth fixing? I could be wrong.