# How can I "unwrap" columns which contain multiple items?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame where one of the columns is a string representation of a `set`. Is it possible to "unwrap" any rows which are like this?

An example:

```
     ColA                 ColB                    ColC   ColD
0    "one item in a set"  "{'item 1'}"            "..."  "..."
1    "several in a set"   "{'item 1', 'item 2'}"  "..."  "..."
...
```

Should become:

```
     ColA                 ColB       ColC   ColD 
0    "one item in a set"  'item 1'   "..."  "..."
1    "several in a set"   'item 1'   "..."  "..." 
2    "several in a set"   'item 2'   "..."  "..."
...
```

Comment: It contains strings when I first receive it, but I've written [this function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34065663/1706564) to convert it if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

```
df2 = df.colB.str[1:-1].str.split(',', expand=True)
df2 = df2.stack().reset_index()
df2 = df2.drop('level_1', axis=1).rename(columns={0: 'colB'}).set_index('level_0')
df = df.drop('colB', axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
```

After removing the `{}`, `.split()` on `','` `expand` to new columns and `.stack()`, then clean up.

Comment: There are other columns too. I'll edit the question to show them as I don't think this answer will work in this case.

Comment: Are there other columns that you need to unwrap at the same time, or other columns you could append to the index?

Comment: They could be appended to the index. There are actually two columns I need to unwrap but they can be done one after the other.

Comment: If you have a lot of columns, it may be easier to take the 'set' column with a single column that has unique values so you can merge back into the original frame after unwrapping.

Comment: I'm getting `IndexError: cannot do a non-empty take from an empty axes.` on the `df.stack().reset_index()` line. There are 12 columns in total.

Comment: And no columns have unique values until after I've done this unwrapping, though there is a combination of two columns which uniquely identifies a row.

Comment: Updated to unwrap separately and then merge back.

Comment: That works perfectly. The only change I've made is to simplify the first line to: `df[col].str[1:-1].str.split(',', expand=True)` (fwiw, this means it will also work for `str` representations of lists).

Comment: Another gotcha is I needed to `df.reset_index()` before repeating for the second column.